# Hibernate: Composite primary key - foreign key: How individual fields are mapped between two tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, composite-primary-key

I am trying to understand OneToOne mapping between two Entities in hibernate with one more condition that primary key (and so foreign key) must be composite.

## UserID embeddable type:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserID  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int ssnID;
    private int uniqueNum;
    // getters and setters..
}
```

## VehicleID embeddable type:

```
@Embeddable
public class VehicleID implements Serializable {
    private int vehicleID;
    private int regNum;
    // getters and setters
}
```

## Vehicle Entity having composite primary key VehicleID:

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VehicleID vehicleID;
    private String description;
    // getters and setters..
}
```

## UserInfo Entity having composite priamary key UserID  and is owning-side entity for OneToOne relationship between UserInfo and Vehicle:

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo {
    private String full_name;
    @EmbeddedId
    UserID userID;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="XYZ_ID") , @JoinColumn(name="ABC_Num")})
    Vehicle veh;

    // getters, setters and other code
}
```

## When I run this program, the below is the SQL output from Hibernate:

> Hibernate: drop table UserInfo if exists
>
> Hibernate: drop table Vehicle if exists
>
> Hibernate: create table UserInfo (ssnID integer not null, uniqueNum integer not null, full_name varchar(255), XYZ_ID integer, ABC_Num integer, primary key (ssnID, uniqueNum))
>
> Hibernate: create table Vehicle (regNum integer not null, vehicleID integer not null, description varchar(255), primary key (regNum, vehicleID))
>
> Hibernate: alter table UserInfo add constraint FKlbuhulsmr2lghirdvem61b9lb foreign key (XYZ_ID, ABC_Num) references Vehicle

In short, `UserInfo` is the owning-side entity and having `OneToOne` relationship with `Vehicle` entity (which has composite VehicleID as primary key).

## My doubt is here:

In `UserInfo` entity, we specify the `OneToOne` relationship (and the annotations):

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="XYZ_ID") , @JoinColumn(name="ABC_Num")})
Vehicle veh;
```

As can be seen above that in `UserInfo` table, we are having a composite foreign key on `Vehicle` table, and name of the `JoinColumn` specifying as `XYZ_ID` and `ABC_Num`.

My doubt is to which fields would `XYZ_ID` and `ABC_Num` correspond to in `Vehicle` table?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: I don't understand what XYZ_ID and ABC_Num is. This should be vehicleID and regNum in my opinion. Why do you have these names in the JoinColumns?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Yes, they should be given sensible names; but to what fields in the other table they would get matched to?

Comment: Hibernate will create vehicleID and regNum in the UserInfo table as well. Simply change the JoinColumns to the correct names.

Comment: Yes those columns it will get created in UserInfo table, but to which columns they would get matched in the other table (as they are acting as foreign key). This is my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the Vehical primary key (ssnID, uniqueNum)

Comment: Yes that is correct, but individually, which field it would match to? For example, if I write XYZ_ID with which column it would have relationship with the VehicleID ( it has two fields). This is my confusion :(

Comment: Oh I see. If you just use name then it will match a column with the same name. You could also define referencedColumnName if this column has a different name.

Comment: Thanks , so is it good practice to name as per the matching individual fields in referencing table?

Comment: Yes. I recommend reading this book https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns